# How write an XPath expression for a list of objects?

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to write XPath expression to search in XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetTest>
<Result>
<name>ABC</name>
</Result>
<Result>
<name>DEF</name>
</Result>
<Result>
<name>GHI</name>
</Result>
</GetTest>
```

And my XPath Expression:

```
//GetTest/Result[0]/name
```

I want to obtain: ABC

Anybody knows why it isn't working?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `.//GetTest/Result[0]/name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your misunderstanding was due to index counting.
**XPath starts counting at 1 (and not zero).**

So use

```
//GetTest/Result[1]/name
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
//Result[1]/*/text()
```

Should output:

```
ABC
```